# "Step Over" and "Step Into" in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have noticed that using F10 - Step Over in VS automatically skips my functions. Why is that?
I did noticed that F11- Step Into, does enter my functions, however it enters the implementation code of the functions I am using from the various C libraries, which is really annoying.

Is there any way I can run step by step inside my functions without entering the implementation code of the included libraries?

Comment: Step over the C library functions and step into your own functions.

Comment: There is no difference between your code and someone else's code, just alternate between _over_ and _into_ depending on what you want...

Comment: Step Into your function calls, but Step Over the external function calls.

Comment: why are people voting this as not a real question? its a good question. the answer may be "no"

Comment: Or, put **break-points** at *your* functions, step-into them and hit *continue* at the end of each, to skip to the next break-point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is annoying, especially if you happen to call several functions just to get parameters into yours. You can use step out (Shift+F11) to quickly get out of uninteresting code. (and then F11 to get into the next one)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's an undocumented feature which allows you to not step into any of a list of functions you specify.  See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx) for an example of how to set that up.  But again, since it's an undocumented feature, it could break with future versions of Visual Studio, and it may not always behave reliably.

Answer (score 2):

You could **step into** your function and then **step over** instructions inside your functions.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that you have multiple function calls that are part of the same expression and you're only interested in stepping into one of them, the "Step into specific" functionality added in VC++ 2008 might be helpful.

Just right click on the line and select "Step into specific" - you'll get a list of functions involved in the expression and can choose which one you want to step into.

On my machine it's also bound to keystroke Shift-Alt-F11.