# `No Source available` when debugging Intel Fortran in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, fortran, intel-fortran

I am debugging the following Fortran code on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012+Intel Visual Fortran:

```
program customarray

implicit none
real, allocatable, dimension(:):: vector
integer :: nelements, i
real :: sum

print *, 'enter how many values you have'
read *, nelements
allocate(vector(nelements))
print *, 'enter the values'
sum = 0.0

do i=1,nelements
    read *, vector(i)
    sum = sum+vector(i)
end do
    
end program customarray
```

As I step through the code using the debugger "step into" tool. Everything runs as expected. However as soon as I reach the very last line

```
end program customarray
```

I get a the following dialog box:

[image]

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I am frustrated because it runs smoothly when I "Run without debugging" and does not display the same error.

Comment: What kind of source would you expect to be available after the program finished? Why is it frustrating? You went through the whole program and the work is done. Or not?

Comment: `Step into` probably just steps into the code that finishes the run and returns to windows. There is nothing interesting there and if it is it is not your Fortran code, it is some internal bookkeeping. What do you want to see there? Why can't you use `Step over` (or the VS equivalent)?

Comment: I didn't expect the program to output any source file. The work is done, yes. The question is : I would like to understand why this error appears, and how I can avoid it when I step through the code.

Comment: It is not an error, it is an information for you.

Comment: so you are saying "End program" is like a function call that goes outside of my source code to close out the black output window via Windows? If so why doesn't "start program" do the same?

Comment: It does, but your debugging starts after it is finished. But there are ways how to debug even the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `end program` with `Step Into` you are entering the code generated by the compiler to finish the program run and return to Windows.

`Step Into` will enter any function executed by the program, even internal libraries (might be set-up slightly differently for Fortran). See ["Step Over" and "Step Into" in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347770/step-over-and-step-into-in-visual-studio)

With `Step Over` or `Step Out` you should be able to skip this finishing internal code, but with `Step Into` you are asking the debugger to take you there.

And, of course, no source is available in that region, because that code executed there is not your user code. It may or may not be compiled C code or even parts of machine code directly inserted there by the compiler.

Similar behaviour can happen at the start of the `program`. You can also enter the procedures executed by the program when preparing the environment to be able to execute your code. If you just want to debug your code, start debugging at a line corresponding to your executable statement.

Comment: Actually I just realized that "step over" does not really do the trick. When debugging and stepping over the program from line 1 ("start program customarray"_it jumps to a source file called crt0.c. This is highly annoying, I just want to step through my own source file without jumping into all this other stuff. Should I start a new question or cancel acceptance of the answer for this question?

Comment: Well, do not Step Over the whole program! Press Step Over only when you really want to skip something. Otherwise use Step Into!

Comment: You can unaccept any answer at any time. I don't recommend starting a new question now.

Comment: Allright, lets say I place a breakpoint on line 1 for my fortran program. Then I click on "step over". It jumps to crt0.c. Then I stop debugging. Then I click on "step into". It jumps to crt0.c. Same thing. It looks like for somereason in this case there is not difference between 'step over' and 'step into'.

Comment: But why on Earth you press Step Over at line 1??? Press Step Into there.

Comment: The same thing happens whether I "step over" or "step into" please see my previous comment

Comment: But from where does it jump to `ctr0.c`? What you are doing differently in comparison with the original situation in the question?

Comment: I am stepping it from line 1 now. I moved the breakpoint from line 19 to line 1

Comment: Just don't do that... You are now in the internal start procedures I was talking about. Various things happen at `end program` and various things happen at `program` start. Just don't debug them if you are not interested in them...

Comment: so theres no way to have the debug screen stay in one source file? I want to step it all the way, line by line. including the start and end program, and staying in the fortran without jumping to another window. Is there any way to do that? Theres got to be...

Comment: Just set the breakpoint at the first executable line in your program. What do you want to debug in the start of the program? There is nothing interesting for you. There are some things, but you don't like them. So don't start there if you don't like them.

Comment: And don't be surprised it will take you somewhere if you press `Step Into` on a `write` or `print` statement. It will also take you to some internals in some other source file. That's how it is. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347770/step-over-and-step-into-in-visual-studio again.