# Visual Studio: preventing debugger from stepping outside current solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, fortran, intel-fortran

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764229/no-source-available-when-debugging-intel-fortran-in-visual-studio/42764671#42764671) question in which I was trying to troubleshoot an error caused by the debugger.

My question is simple. I have a large Intel Visual Fortran solution loaded into my solution explorer on Visual Studio 2012. I would like to step through this solution (using STEP INTO) in Debug mode but preventing it from stepping outside the current solution. Lines like `start program` or `end subroutine` throw me outside my solution and open up procedures Windows uses to enable Fortran to start a program or end a subroutine.

The reason I want to use "Step into" is because I would, of course, still want to step into the subroutines and functions contained within my solution to understand and watch what they are doing.

One would think such an option would be contained in Debug > Options and Settings. However as the following image shows, it is not apparent to me what would trigger the behavior I am looking for.

[image]

The reason for wanting to trigger this behavior, aside from the fact that it is practical for my purposes, is that stepping into the very Fortran commands themselves slows down the system and I cannot step through 3 lines of code without having the whole thing freeze/stop responding.

Comment: Just to make sure. You want to stay in your own code and you don't want to step into any internals. Does it also concern stepping into things like intrinsic procedures and statements like `open/write/read` or `allocate/deallocate`?

Comment: BTW for such a specific version you are quite likely to get a quicker answer at the official Intel support forum.

Comment: And also note that even if you will find a solution, you will still need to switch between Step Into / Step Over / Step Out during typical debugging. Your rarely want to descent into every procedure in sufficiently complex programs.

Comment: TO answer your question: I would not like to step into intrinsic procedures either. I just want to limit the debugging to my solution and my solution only. In this case I do believe I want to descend into most procedures since a big part of my job is to understand exactly how this program works.

Comment: A solution is defined as a construct which contains several projects which in turn may contain several source files. I don't want to stay within the same source file necessarily. I want to be able to jump to other source files, provided theye are within the same solution...

Comment: Alright, it was a gap in my knowledge of VS, I rolled back the question.